# Using Popen to invoke adb sendevent

Tags: python

I am running into a strange issue, running `adb shell sendevent x x x` commands from commandline works fine, but when I use any of the following:

`subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'shell', 'sendevent', 'x', 'x','x'])`
 `subprocess.Popen('adb shell sendevent x x x', shell=True)`
 `subprocess.call(['adb', 'shell', 'sendevent', 'x', 'x','x'])`

They all fail - the simulated touch even that works in a shell script does not work properly when called through python. Furthermore I tried `adb push` the shell script to the device, and using `adb shell /system/sh /sdcard/script.sh` I was able to run it successfully, but when I try to run that commandline through python, the script fails.

What's even stranger, is that he script runs, but for example, it does not seem to execute the command `sleep 1` half way through the script, `echo` commands work, `sendevent` commands don't seem to work.

Doesn't even seem possible, but there it is. How do I run a set of `adb shell sendevent x x x` commands through python?

Comment: Do *any* `adb` commands work from Python? Perhaps it is not in your path.

Comment: Don't you have to set the `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` for this?

Comment: yes all other `adb` commands work. I don't think I need `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, all that does is allow me to see the output of that command, and/or use the output in my code, which I don't need because there is no output... right?